# How is cout << <variable> different from cout << <mathematical-expression>?

Tags: c++, floating-point, cout, integer-arithmetic

I'm trying to solve this problem: https://www.codechef.com/FEB222C/problems/WCC

I've solved this problem and have successfully submitted the solution, but I'm getting 'WRONG ANSWER' error in an alternate approach in one test case:

My successful submission approach is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        int X;
        cin >> X;
        int prize = 100 * X;
        string str;
        cin >> str;
        int carlsenPoints = 0;
        int chefPoints = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            if(str[i] == 'C'){
                carlsenPoints += 2;
            }
            else if(str[i] == 'N'){
                chefPoints += 2;
            }
            else if(str[i] == 'D'){
                carlsenPoints++;
                chefPoints++;
            }
        }
        int sum;
        if(carlsenPoints > chefPoints){
            sum = 0.6 * prize;
        }
        else if(carlsenPoints == chefPoints){
            sum = 0.55 * prize;
        }
        else if(carlsenPoints < chefPoints){
            sum = 0.4 * prize;
        }
        cout << sum << endl;
    }
}
```

The above solution works well. I'm having problems with the below solution, which gives 'WRONG ANSWER' in one test case.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        int X;
        cin >> X;
        string str;
        cin >> str;
        int carlsenPoints = 0;
        int chefPoints = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            if(str[i] == 'C'){
                carlsenPoints += 2;
            }
            else if(str[i] == 'N'){
                chefPoints += 2;
            }
            else if(str[i] == 'D'){
                carlsenPoints++;
                chefPoints++;
            }
        }
        if(carlsenPoints > chefPoints){
            cout << 0.6 * 100 * X << endl;
        }
        else if(carlsenPoints == chefPoints){
            cout << 0.55 * 100 * X << endl;
        }
        else if(carlsenPoints < chefPoints){
            cout << 0.4 * 100 * X << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Why is the second solution resulting in an error?
To me, they're both pretty much same.

**TL;DR :**

How is:

```
int sum;
        int prize = 100*X;
        if(carlsenPoints > chefPoints){
            sum = 0.6 * prize;
        }
        else if(carlsenPoints == chefPoints){
            sum = 0.55 * prize;
        }
        else if(carlsenPoints < chefPoints){
            sum = 0.4 * prize;
        }
        cout << sum << endl;
```

different from :

```
        if(carlsenPoints > chefPoints){
            cout << 0.6 * 100 * X << endl;
        }
        else if(carlsenPoints == chefPoints){
            cout << 0.55 * 100 * X << endl;
        }
        else if(carlsenPoints < chefPoints){
            cout << 0.4 * 100 * X << endl;
        }
```

?

Comment: Unrelated: Another thing to watch out for is [Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). `cout << x ^ y;` will not compile because the compiler sees `(cout << x) ^ y;`

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, I know about operator precedence and `*` has higher precedence than `<<` so it shouldn't be a problem.
Someone mentioned `manipulators`, so I'm still looking into what that is . .

Comment: Some reading on that: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip

Comment: Precedence isn't a problem for you, but if you are the only person that ever seeks help from this question, the question failed.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah okay. I think the problem I had is something related to the working of `cout`
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/

Comment: It isn't, fundamentally. `cout << x` is an expression that evaluates `cout` and `x` and then uses them as operands to `<<`.  `cout << 0.6 * 100 * X` does the same.  `0.6 * 100 * X` is evaluated as an expression in its own right. Need to account for properties of operators though - precedence and associativity - `cout << 0.6 * 100 * X` is equivalent to `cout << (0.6 * 100 * X)` but `cout << x ^ y` is equivalent to `(cout << x) ^ y` since binary `*` has higher precedence than `<<` which has higher precedence than `^` (this won't compile as no form of `^` accepts a stream as left-hand operand).

Answer (score 2):

In the first program the variable `sum` is declared as having the type `int`.

```
int sum;
```

So this statement

```
cout << sum << endl;
```

outputs an integer.

In the second program expressions like this

```
0.6 * 100 * X
```

have the type double.

So this statement

```
cout << 0.6 * 100 * X << endl;
```

outputs a floating point value.

Comment: For the input: 

1
100
CCCCCCCCCCCCCC 

The output is 6000 and not 6000.00
Why?

Comment: @SatvikPopli Because you do not use manipulators like for example fixed.

Comment: For the input: 1 100 CCCCCCCCCCCCCC 
If the result were a float, shouldn't the output be 6000.00? It still shows 6000.

Comment: @SatvikPopli You can include the header #include <iomanip> and try to output for example std::cout << std::fixed << 6000.0 << '\n'; Without the manipulator std:: fixed it will be outputted as an integer value without the decimal point.

Comment: yeah, this shows an output of the float and not in int format. But I'm pretty new to this.
My question is: if I `cout` a float, will it show an int if the decimal places are all zero? Is this how `cout` is programmed to work?

Comment: @SatvikPopli It considers only 6 digits of precision. For example this code snippet        double d = 100.0000001;

        std::cout << d << '\n'; outputs 100.

Comment: Got your point about std::fixed after reading this: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/

Comment: @SatvikPopli That is visually 100.0000001 can be outputted like 100. But then it is compared with the integer value 100  (100 == 100.0000001 ) then the result is false.